# Bash: Want to move certain amount of files, that contains spaces to a different directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line

So I'm quite new with `bash` and Stack Overflow in general, so forgive me if I may be missing something.

I've been trying to create a script that moves a certain amount of files (ex: 3 files), that may contain spaces (like `"hello world.txt"`), to another directory.

I've tried a few different ways to get the files with spaces, but have all proven a little difficult and finally narrowed it down to just using `*.csv`. For instance the code will look like (simplified):

```
for file in *.csv; #grab 3 files
do
     echo "$file";
     mv "$file" "$TDIR"
done
```

I only want to move a certain amount of files, like 3. `$TDIR` in this case is a target directory to move them to.

I've done it this way because I'm able to grab the whole filename `"Hello World.txt"` instead of grabbing `"Hello"` and `"World.txt"`.

I've tried using different things like:

```
ls -p | grep -v / | head -3
```

but it gives me the above result where it creates 2 files (the spaces causing problems).

Sorry it's kind of long but I've been struggling with this and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a large number of files that match `*.csv`, but you only want to move some of them?

Comment: Use `find(1)`, which allows specifying an arbitrary expression for what should be matched, then use its `-exec mv {} "$TDIR" \;` option

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes, sorry for not being very detailed, but I have let's say about 1000 files in a directory and I want to move about 100 every 10 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum necessary change is to use the loop you have, but simply break out early:

```
((count = 3))
for file in *.csv ; do
     echo "$file"
     mv "$file" "$TDIR"
     ((count--))
     [[ ${count} -eq 0 ]] && break;
done
```

The only real *potential* downside of this solution is that it may fail if you have a truly stupendous number of files, so many that the shell globbing starts to struggle under the load. However, I find it's often easier than trying to remember or research the ninety-two `find` parameters that will enable the same behaviour :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the edits. This solution seemed to have worked haven't tested on many files yet, but I also have a few questions, hope you don't mind answering. Why do you have the count variable in double parenthesis and not simply as count= 3?

Comment: @murther: because it let's me format it nicely with spaces :-) More seriously, I prefer this since it allows proper expressions such as `((averageCharsPerLine = CharsInFile / LinesInFile))`. Technically, it's not needed in this case but I still use it for consistency.

Comment: Seems cleaner to do `((--count)) || break`

Comment: @murther More importantly, double-parentheses allow you to do proper math much more naturally, instead of having to use `expr` or `let` everywhere, and allows you to use C style expressions. See [Performing Math calculation in Bash](https://www.shell-tips.com/2010/06/14/performing-math-calculation-in-bash/) and/or google for _"bash math"_.

Comment: Thanks you all for your feedback. Much appreciated!